External Transfer MicroDeposit Event
Is there an EES Event that kicks off when a customer attempts to initiate a new external transfer account? If not, is there an event that sends whenever a micro-deposit is initiated for setting up the account for external transfers?
I've taken a look at the Jxchange documentation and haven't been able to conclusively determine if there is an event that is initiated with these types of processes. I've also looked in the Banno Admin API documentation since the external transfer would theoretically be initiated through Banno but was unable to find anything there either.

I was able to figure this out myself eventually by using the History > History Events Retrieval > /person-events endpoint and using the query parameter change=ExternalTransferMicroDepositSent
